# Setting Depth for Apache-Nutch Crawler

Tags: nutch, depth

How to set depth for Apache-Nutch Crawler?

Below command says crawl is deprecated:

```
bin/nutch crawl seed.txt -dir crawler/stat -depth 1 -topN 5
```

I tried with bin/crawl instead of crawl. For that, I am getting error:

> class cannot be loaded : bin.crawl

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to set maximum depth, you should use the scoring-depth plugin. The crawl script allows you to define the number of iteration, which is an upper limit on the depth, but not the same thing.
The correct format for the crawl command is:

```
bin/crawl -s seed.txt crawler/stat 1
```

As with other Nutch scripts, simply run bin/crawl with no parameters to see the help message that explains how to use it.